# Dynamic add attributes on component in Angular pre compile

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

I have component that is used multiple times, 58 times to be exakt. The only thing that differs between them is unique attributes to add validations. What I want to do is to add a array of attributes to my template before is compiled. Is this possible to achieve when working with a Angular component?

component.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('upaApp')
        .component('component', {
            bindings: {
                inputAttributes: '@',
            },
            controller: controller,
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'app/component/component.html'
        });

    function controller() {
        var $ctrl = this;
    }
})();
```

component.html

```
<input {{ $ctrl.inputAttributes }}
       class="form-control"
       type="text" />
```

When I use the component `<component input-attributes="directive1, directive2"></component>` it doesn't render out my string and even if it did I would not be sure that it would work. So is there a way to dynamically be able to set the attributes in AngularJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was actually a very simple solution on my problem. You could use ng-model to send the value to the component. And when I placed my directives on the component it validates accordingly since it can access the value from ng-model.

Answer (score 0):

Is this angular 1 or 2?
Ill assume the former.

I dont know of a way to place a string as an attribute. What you could do as a workaround is conditionally insert attributes with the ng-attr- attribute. This will insert the attribute if the variable is not undefined.
maybe something like this:

```
$scope.ctrl.inputAttributes = {
    directive1:undefined, //this one wont show 
    directive2:"this one will show"// as directive2="this one will show"
}
```

then in your markup:

```
<input ng-attr-directive1="ctrl.inputAttributes.directive1"
       ng-attr-directive2="ctrl.inputAttributes.directive2"
       class="form-control"
       type="text" />
```

https://www.thinkingmedia.ca/2015/03/conditionally-add-a-html-element-attribute-value-in-angularjs/

EDIT: it may not be clean, but you could create a directive that compiles html.

```
app.directive('dynamicAttributes', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        attributes: '@'
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        var h = '<input '+scope.attributes + ' class="form-control" type="text" />';
        elem.replaceWith($compile(h)(scope));
    }
}
});
```

then in your DOM

```
<dynamic-attributes attributes="1 2 3"></dynamic-attributes>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brhardwick/nx16zdrL/1/

Comment: It's Angular 1 and they way you point out is they way we have solved it today. We have 85 directives so it's not a good solution.

Comment: check my edit. you may need to tweak if the directives are complex. but this should get you going